# Is setubandha by bhaskaraya online pdf available?

Tags: resource, sri-vidya

Is "Setubandha" by bhaskaraya available online in Sanskrit/ Hindi/ English. if not where can i get a book ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Yes, the Sanskrit text is available.*

I have found one book of **Yogini Hridaya** on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Saraswati_Bhavana_Texts_Series/07YoginiHridayaWithDipikaOfAmritanandaSetubandhaOfBhaskararaya-GopinathKaviraj1924sbg) which contains two commentaries on it: i) Dipika of Amritananda and ii) **Setubandah of Bhaskara Raya**.

> [image]

You can read book online on can [*get it in pdf format*](https://archive.org/download/Saraswati_Bhavana_Texts_Series/07YoginiHridayaWithDipikaOfAmritanandaSetubandhaOfBhaskararaya-GopinathKaviraj1924sbg.pdf).

You will find YoginiHridiya along with Dipika and Setubandha in Sanskrit:

> [image]